# Porqué, la transacción continua, siendo que hay un error en un metodo?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms

Buen día tengo tres metodos que son parte de una sola transaccion, parte de una transaccion para registrar una compra, estoy probando si la transaccion funciona, primero elimine la tabla del Kardex, y sí, funciono correctamente se revierten los cambios, ahora cuando a proposito paso un valor cero, no entra al bucle foreach, pero hace commint, cosa que no debe ser así, porque los datos del kardex no estam persistidos en la base de datos, les mostraré el codigo.

```
public class BD_RegistroCompraDetalle_Kardex
```

{

```
public void RegistrarCompraMaestroCompraDetalleKardexDetalle(EN_MaestroCompra maestro, List<EN_DetalleCompra> detalleCompra, List<EN_KardexDetalle> kardexDetalle)
{
    BDConexion bdConexion = new BDConexion();
    SqlTransaction transaction = null;

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = bdConexion.AbrirConexion())
        {
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

            // Registrar el Maestro y obtener el IdMaestro
            int maestroId = RegistrarMaestroCompra(maestro, connection, transaction);

            // Asignar el IdMaestro a cada detalle
            foreach (var detail in detalleCompra)
            {
                detail.IdMaestroCompra = maestroId;
            }
            // Registrar los Detalles
            RegistrarDetalleCompra(detalleCompra, connection, transaction);

            // Registrar los Detalles del Kardex
            BD_RegistrarDetalleKardex(kardexDetalle, connection, transaction);

            // Confirmar la transacción
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //// Manejar la excepción y deshacer la transacción si ocurre un error
        //if (transaction != null && transaction.Connection != null)
        //{
        transaction.Rollback();
        //}
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
public int RegistrarMaestroCompra(EN_MaestroCompra maestro, SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction)
{
    // Output parameter to obtain the IdCompra
    SqlParameter outputParameter = new SqlParameter("@IdMaestroCompra", SqlDbType.Int)
    {
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    };

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_RegistrarMaestroCompra", connection, transaction))
    {

        command.CommandTimeout = 20;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumeroCompra", maestro.NumeroCompra);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NroDocumento", maestro.NroDocumento);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaCompra", maestro.FechaCompra);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaRegistro", maestro.FechaRegistro);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdProveedor", maestro.IdProveedor);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubTotalCompra", maestro.SubTotalCompra);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalCompra", maestro.TotalCompra);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModalidadPago", maestro.ModalidadPago);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecibiConforme", maestro.RecibiConforme);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatosAdicional", maestro.DatosAdicional);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipoDocCompra", maestro.TipoDocCompra);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdUsuario", maestro.IdUsuario);


        // Add output parameter
        command.Parameters.Add(outputParameter);

        // Execute the stored procedure
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Obtain the MaestroId from the output parameter
        return Convert.ToInt32(outputParameter.Value);
        //return outputParameter.Value.ToString();

    }
}

public void RegistrarDetalleCompra(List<EN_DetalleCompra> detalle, SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction)
{
    foreach (var filaDetalle in detalle)
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_RegistrarDetalleCompra", connection, transaction))
        {
            command.CommandTimeout = 20;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdMaestroCompra", filaDetalle.IdMaestroCompra);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdProducto", filaDetalle.IdProducto);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrecioUnitario", filaDetalle.PrecioUnitario);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cantidad", filaDetalle.Cantidad);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Importe", filaDetalle.Importe);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}

private void BD_RegistrarDetalleKardex(List<EN_KardexDetalle> kardexDetalle, SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var filaDetalle in kardexDetalle)
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_CrearKardexDetalle", connection, transaction))
            {
                command.CommandTimeout = 20;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdKardex", filaDetalle.IdKardex);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item", filaDetalle.Item);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumeroDocumento", filaDetalle.NumeroDocumento);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DetalleOperacion", filaDetalle.DetalleOperacion);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CantidadIngreso", filaDetalle.CantidadIngreso);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrecioIngreso", filaDetalle.PrecioIngreso);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalIngreso", filaDetalle.TotalIngreso);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CantidadSalida", filaDetalle.CantidadSalida);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrecioSalida", filaDetalle.PrecioSalida);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalSalida", filaDetalle.TotalSalida);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CantidadSaldo", filaDetalle.CantidadSaldo);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Promedio", filaDetalle.Promedio);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Costo_Total_Saldo", filaDetalle.Costo_Total_Saldo);
                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdProducto", detalle.IdProducto);
                Console.WriteLine("Pasó por aquí");
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

    }
    catch (NullReferenceException e)
    {

        throw new NullReferenceException(
    "Parameter index is out of range.", e);
    }


}
```

El codigo en la parte superior es parte de una sola transaccion, pero no funciona ya que sin guardar datos en la tabla kardex de igual forma hacer el commint

Por ejemplo, cuando se le pasa Cero (0), a foreach (var filaDetalle in kardexDetalle), mas propiamente  a kardexDetalle = 0, no entra al cuerpo del foreach, pero de igual forma el codigo sigue su curso

por lo mismo, cuando a kardexDetalle = null, y usando el bloque try catch, la aplicacion cae, o termina la ejecucion y no respeta el uso de try

que he intentado hacer:
he querido preguntar con un bloque if kardexDetalle = null que no haga lo demás, pero de igual manera me lleva al Commit()
Por favor como consiguo hacer que la transaccion haga el transaction.Rollback();
muchas gracias por la colaboración

Comment: Tu rollback esta dentro de la excepcion.. todo lo que nombras, no genera una excepcion, es mas, no veo porque, no entrar a un bloque for, deberia provocar un rollback. Creo que hay algo mal en tu logica, de como funciona una transaccion. No es por tablas, es por lo que vos digas... Entonces, se va a hacer el commit, salvo que haya una excepcion, o que claramente digas, con estas condiciones quiero que haya rollback...

Comment: Para que te queda mas claro, todo lo que decis que no funciona, en realidad esta funcionando exactamente como le dijiste que funcionara.. El problema no es el codigo, es tu logica...

Comment: gbianchi, bendiciones buen día, para probar si funciona la transacción eliminé la tabla y así si funciona, pero cuando paso un kardex vacío, no se ejecuta el cuerpo del foreach y por consiguiente no se guardan los datos, eso cuenta como un error, pero el commit se ejecuta. Ahora cuando paso un NULL se cae el programa, pese a que estoy controlando con try

Comment: Que no entre a un for, no cuenta como ningun error. Para nadie.. eso es un problema de tu logica. Si le pasas Null, abria que ver a donde lo esta agarrando y donde esta fallando... pero todo lo que describis, son problemas de logica con tu codigo, y el unico que va a poder solucionarlo sos vos...

Comment: Estas confundiendo errores en tu logica de negocios, con erroes en tu codigo... tenes problemas con tu logica de negocios.. por ejemplo, si no entra al for, deberias controlar al principio si hay registros, y evitar que directamente se inicie la transaccion, o hacer el rollback al momento de darte cuenta y salir.. no por el catch, si no por la logica directa...

Comment: Estimado, es lo que he intentado hacer, por ejemplo if kardexDetalle.Count==0 que se salga, y se sale pero de ahí adonde dejo dirigirlo. Esa es la parte que no sé, porque he intentado con return pero de igual manera se va a donde invoco al método y hace el commit

Comment: Dondo el return? todo lo que me describis, son errores de logica de negocios... donde esta ese count??' de donde sale??? cual es el problema??? me suena a que tenes un lio de cual es tu idea dentro de ese metodo, por todas las llamadas.. porque, por ejemplo, las llamadas no devuelve un booleano que diga si se hizo o no correctamente??? no podemos corregir algo que no esta mal, y no entendemos...

Comment: Gracias, voy a analizar mi código conforme a tus comentarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extrañamente, a las tablas agregué un campo autonumerico como PK, y funcionó correctamente. lo digo así porque el campo que tenía como primary Key no era identity.
adjunto el código, no sé si esta bien estructurado, el tema es que funciona.
y esta sería mi respuesta.

```
    public class BD_RegistroCompraDetalle_Kardex
{

    public void RegistrarCompraMaestroCompraDetalleKardexDetalle(EN_MaestroCompra maestro, List<EN_DetalleCompra> detalleCompra, List<EN_KardexDetalle> kardexDetalle)
    {
        BDConexion bdConexion = new BDConexion();
        SqlTransaction transaction = null;

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = bdConexion.AbrirConexion())
            {
                transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

                // Registrar el Maestro y obtener el IdMaestro
                int maestroId = RegistrarMaestroCompra(maestro, connection, transaction);

                // Asignar el IdMaestro a cada detalle
                foreach (var detail in detalleCompra)
                {
                    detail.IdMaestroCompra = maestroId;
                }
                // Registrar los Detalles
                RegistrarDetalleCompra(detalleCompra, connection, transaction);

                // Registrar los Detalles del Kardex
                BD_RegistrarDetalleKardex(kardexDetalle, connection, transaction);

                // Confirmar la transacción
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
            transaction.Rollback();
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public int RegistrarMaestroCompra(EN_MaestroCompra maestro, SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction)
    {
        // Output parameter to obtain the IdCompra
        SqlParameter outputParameter = new SqlParameter("@IdMaestroCompra", SqlDbType.Int)
        {
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        };

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_RegistrarMaestroCompra", connection, transaction))
        {

            command.CommandTimeout = 20;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumeroCompra", maestro.NumeroCompra);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NroDocumento", maestro.NroDocumento);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaCompra", maestro.FechaCompra);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaRegistro", maestro.FechaRegistro);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdProveedor", maestro.IdProveedor);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubTotalCompra", maestro.SubTotalCompra);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalCompra", maestro.TotalCompra);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModalidadPago", maestro.ModalidadPago);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecibiConforme", maestro.RecibiConforme);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatosAdicional", maestro.DatosAdicional);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipoDocCompra", maestro.TipoDocCompra);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdUsuario", maestro.IdUsuario);


            // Add output parameter
            command.Parameters.Add(outputParameter);

            // Execute the stored procedure
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Obtain the MaestroId from the output parameter
            return Convert.ToInt32(outputParameter.Value);
            //return outputParameter.Value.ToString();

        }
    }

    public void RegistrarDetalleCompra(List<EN_DetalleCompra> detalle, SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction)
    {
        foreach (var filaDetalle in detalle)
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_RegistrarDetalleCompra", connection, transaction))
            {
                command.CommandTimeout = 20;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdMaestroCompra", filaDetalle.IdMaestroCompra);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdProducto", filaDetalle.IdProducto);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrecioUnitario", filaDetalle.PrecioUnitario);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cantidad", filaDetalle.Cantidad);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Importe", filaDetalle.Importe);

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    private void BD_RegistrarDetalleKardex(List<EN_KardexDetalle> kardexDetalle, SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction)
    {

        if (kardexDetalle != null)
        {
            foreach (var filaDetalle in kardexDetalle)
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_CrearKardexDetalle", connection, transaction))
                {
                    command.CommandTimeout = 20;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdKardex", filaDetalle.IdKardex);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item", filaDetalle.Item);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumeroDocumento", filaDetalle.NumeroDocumento);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DetalleOperacion", filaDetalle.DetalleOperacion);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CantidadIngreso", filaDetalle.CantidadIngreso);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrecioIngreso", filaDetalle.PrecioIngreso);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalIngreso", filaDetalle.TotalIngreso);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CantidadSalida", filaDetalle.CantidadSalida);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrecioSalida", filaDetalle.PrecioSalida);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalSalida", filaDetalle.TotalSalida);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CantidadSaldo", filaDetalle.CantidadSaldo);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Promedio", filaDetalle.Promedio);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Costo_Total_Saldo", filaDetalle.Costo_Total_Saldo);
                    //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdProducto", detalle.IdProducto);
                    Console.WriteLine("Pasó por aquí");
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {

            //throw new NullReferenceException("Parameter index is out of range.");
            throw new NullReferenceException("Parameter index is out of range.");

        }

    }
```